# Why are polaroids not square?

Tags: polaroid, paper-size

When I used to look at real polaroid photos, I could not help but think that they are not exactly square (I have a mild OCD, I would tell). After so many years my suspicion was proven correct: on [the official Polaroid page specifying the exact dimensions of a polaroid](https://support.polaroid.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012363647-What-are-Polaroid-photo-dimensions-#:%7E:text=Well%2C%20actually%2C%20current%20Polaroid%20film,8.847%20cm%20(total%20area).), it says that the photo area is exactly 3.108 by 3.024 inches (even though, contradicting this, the bottom image shows the photo area to be exactly 3.1 by 3.1 inches, and 3.024 is not 3.1 even when rounded according to normal rules for rounding).

**Why is this the case?** Obviously it is such a trivial matter that nobody else seems to be bothered by it. Still, why was this extremely weird decision made by Polaroid?

Polaroid makes money off of selling ink, so they should have made one side 3.1 inches, and the other one slightly larger than 3.1 inches. And still, the opposite is true.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is any significant technical reason. Which probably means the answer is "you'd have to ask the people that made the decision"...

Comment: If i remember correctly. The paper was square but the image was not, there was some space on the paper that housed the chemical pack. The pack was burst when pulling the paper out and the chemicals then developed the image.

Comment: I don't really understand the question... Why are Polaroids not square... Well, why _should_ they be square?

Comment: @AlaskaMan [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871) You've put anyone who wants to actually write a correct answer in the undesirable position of seeming to plagiarize your comment.

Comment: @Aleksandr Polaroid made money by selling film packs. They made more money using *less* ink per photo than they would using *more* ink per photo if they charged the same amount for each filmpack.

Comment: @xiota All four edges had developer, but the leading edge had more so that the roller could push it all the way through the center of the frame to the other side. The trailing edge also had less than the sides.

Comment: @osullic because that's obviously what their original intention was. Duh. The aspect ratio of the photo area is incredibly close to 1:1. Hello?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [osullic's sentiment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/119817/why-are-polaroids-not-square#comment230707_119817), "why should they be square?" Here are a few observations that may help you feel better about their not being *perfectly* square:

- There are no perfect squares. With good vision or glasses, the corners can be seen to be dull and the edges uneven.
- Tighter engineering tolerances are more costly to produce. This was a film for the masses, and a 2.5% deviation from square is close enough.
- If you measure enough Polaroid images, you'll probably find that there's more variation than the page you reference indicates.
- Image aspect ratio is arbitrary, whether "square" or not. Consider that FujiFilm Instax is provided with a few different aspect ratios.

  [image: Instax Film]